# Do files get closed during an exception exit?

Tags: python, file

Do open files (and other resources) get automatically closed when the script exits due to an exception?

I'm wondering if I need to be closing my resources during my exception handling.

**EDIT**: to be more specific, I am creating a simple log file in my script. I want to know if I need to be concerned about closing the log file explicitly in the case of exceptions.
since my script has a complex, nested, try/except blocks, doing so is somewhat complicated, so if python, CLIB, or the OS is going to close my text file when the script crashes/errors out, I don't want to waste too much time on making sure the file gets closed.

If there is a part in Python manual that talks about this, please refer me to it, but I could not find it.

Comment: Have you done a little experiment to try to find out for yourself? How would you know if a file was "still open"?

Comment: @Floris: an experiment could confirm that it wasn't being closed, but not that it always would be.  (As it happens, it isn't always.)  One way to know if a file hadn't been closed would be if something which happened upon closure didn't happen, e.g. a flush.  This is not the same as being "still open", which the OP doesn't seem to say, even though you put it in quotation marks.

Comment: I think the answer to this is "it depends". At the OS level, all files are definitely closed when a process exits (except for on some old broken OSes), regardless of how/why it exits. However, that does not necessarily mean that pending writes are flushed, finalization/destructor (i.e. `__exit__` methods in `python`) methods are called, etc. If you have certain files which *must* be cleanly shut down regardless of process termination mode, you have to code that yourself. But they will be closed...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, they don't.

Use `with` statement if you want your files to be closed even if an exception occurs.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt):

> The `with` statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with
>   methods defined by a context manager. This allows common
>   **try...except...finally** usage patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#predefined-clean-up-actions):

The `with` statement allows objects like files to be used in a way that ensures they are always cleaned up promptly and correctly.

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

After the statement is executed, the file `f` is always closed, even if a problem was encountered while processing the lines. Other objects which provide predefined clean-up actions will indicate this in their documentation.

Comment: This is correct.  The `with` statement calls the object's `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods when needed.  It will automatically close your file object at the end of the code block, even if an exception is raised.

Comment: @1_CR You can always write your own context manager, and define it's `__enter__`,  `__exit__` methods appropriately. :)

Answer (score 41):

A fairly straightforward question.

Two answers.

One saying, “Yes.”

The other saying, “No!”

Both with significant upvotes.

Who to believe? Let me attempt to clarify.

---

Both answers have some truth to them, and it depends on what you mean by a
file being closed.

First, consider what is meant by closing a file from the operating system’s
perspective.

When a process exits, the operating system [clears up all the resources
that only that process had open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions'_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition,_with_Source_Code). Otherwise badly-behaved programs that
crash but didn’t free up their resources could consume all the system
resources.

If Python was the only process that had that file open, then the file will
be closed. Similarly the operating system will clear up memory allocated by
the process, any networking ports that were still open, and most other
things. There are a few exceptional functions like [`shmat`](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#shm) that create
objects that persist beyond the process, but for the most part the
operating system takes care of everything.

Now, what about closing files from Python’s perspective? If any program
written in any programming language exits, most resources will get cleaned
up—but how does Python handle cleanup inside standard Python programs?

The standard CPython implementation of Python—as opposed to other Python
implementations like Jython—uses reference counting to do most of its
garbage collection. An object has a reference count field. Every time
something in Python gets a reference to some other object, the reference
count field in the referred-to object is incremented. When a reference is
lost, e.g, because a variable is no longer in scope, the reference count is
decremented. When the reference count hits zero, no Python code can reach
the object anymore, so the object gets deallocated. And when it gets
deallocated, [Python calls the `__del__()` destructor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).

Python’s `__del__()` method for files flushes the buffers and closes the
file from the operating system’s point of view. Because of reference
counting, in CPython, if you open a file in a function and don’t return the
file object, then the reference count on the file goes down to zero when
the function exits, and the file is automatically flushed and closed. When
the program ends, CPython dereferences all objects, and all objects have
their destructors called, even if the program ends due to an unhanded
exception. (This does technically fail for the pathological case where you have a [cycle
of objects with destructors](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage),
at least in Python versions [before 3.4](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).)

But that’s just the CPython implementation. Python the language is defined
in the [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/), which is what all Python
implementations are required to follow in order to call themselves
Python-compatible.

The language reference explains resource management in its [data model
section](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html):

> Some objects contain references to “external” resources such as open
>   files or windows. It is understood that these resources are freed when
>   the object is garbage-collected, but since garbage collection is not
>   guaranteed to happen, such objects also provide an explicit way to
>   release the external resource, usually a close() method. Programs are
>   strongly recommended to explicitly close such objects. The
>   ‘try...finally‘ statement and the ‘with‘ statement provide convenient
>   ways to do this.

That is, CPython will usually immediately close the object, but that may
change in a future release, and other Python implementations aren’t even
required to close the object at all.

So, for portability and because [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/),
it’s highly recommended to call `close()` on everything that can be
`close()`d, and to do that in a `finally` block if there is code between
the object creation and `close()` that might raise an exception. Or to use
the `with` syntactic sugar that accomplishes the same thing. If you do
that, then buffers on files will be flushed, even if an exception is
raised.

However, even with the `with` statement, the same underlying mechanisms are
at work. If the program crashes in a way that doesn’t give Python’s
`__del__()` method a chance to run, you can still end up with a corrupt
file on disk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3

import ctypes

# Cast the memory adress 0x0001 to the C function int f()
prototype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(int)
f = prototype(1)

with open('foo.txt', 'w'):
    x.write('hi')
    # Segfault
    print(f())
```

This program produces a zero-length file. It’s an abnormal case, but it
shows that even with the `with` statement resources won’t always
necessarily be cleaned up the way you expect. Python tells the operating
system to open a file for writing, which creates it on disk; Python writes `hi`
into the C library’s `stdio` buffers; and then it crashes before the `with`
statement ends, and because of the apparent memory corruption, it’s not safe
for the operating system to try to read the remains of the buffer and flush them to disk. So the program fails to clean up properly even though there’s a `with` statement. Whoops. Despite this, `close()` and `with` almost always work, and your program is always better off having them than not having them.

So the answer is neither yes nor no. The `with` statement and `close()` are technically not
necessary for most ordinary CPython programs. But not using them results in
non-portable code that will look wrong. And while they are *extremely*
helpful, it is still possible for them to fail in pathological cases.

Comment: To be clear, the 'with' statement doesn't handle the segfault you generated and is no better than my suggestion to just let the underlying libraries close your files on exit. Segfaults are very uncommon in python and protecting against those need a different file strategy such as direct-io, frequent flushing, barriers and etc.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, you’re right that the `with` statement doesn’t handle the segfault. That’s what that example was trying to show, actually. However, (1) the language spec does not require destructors to be called so code that doesn’t explicitly `close()` is nonportable to other Python implementations and future CPython implementations (2) since it’s standard practice to use `with` or `close()`, code that doesn’t use it looks wrong, i.e., it is a “code smell” (3) if you have a lot of open files waiting to be destroyed you can run into `EMFILE Too many open files` errors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they do.

This is a CLIB (at least in cpython) and operating system thing. When the script exits, CLIB will flush and close all file objects. Even if it doesn't (e.g., python itself crashes) the operating system closes its resources just like any other process. It doesn't matter if it was an exception or a normal exit or even if its python or any other program.

Here's a script that writes a file and raises an exception before the file contents have been flushed to disk. Works fine:

```
~/tmp/so$ cat xyz.txt
cat: xyz.txt: No such file or directory
~/tmp/so$ cat exits.py
f = open("xyz.txt", "w")
f.write("hello")
print("file is", open("xyz.txt").read())
assert False

~/tmp/so$ python exits.py
('file is', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exits.py", line 4, in <module>
    assert False
AssertionError
~/tmp/so$ cat xyz.txt
hello
```

Comment: dumb question maybe, what does CLIB stand for?

Comment: CLIB is the C Library. cpython is written in C and uses its internal buffering for file i/o. When you run python, CLIB runs first, does some setup and calls python's main(). Python initializes and runs your scripts. When python exits, it goes back to CLIB which cleans up and does the real exit.

Comment: When your script exits, via normal return, exception or calling os.exit(), python will destroy objects that have gone out of scope. This will likely close the files. Python will then call the std library [exit()](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#exit) which will close and flush any file that remains. You do not need to close the log file explicitly.

Comment: Did you mean `sys.exit([arg])`? There is no `os.exit()`, only `os._exit()` which should not normally be used since it does _not_ flush buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I, as well as other persons in this thread, are left with the question, "Well what is finally true?"

Now, supposing that files are left open in a premature program termination -- and there are a lot of such cases besides exceptions due to file handling -- the only safe way to avoid this, is to read the whole (or part of the) file into a buffer and close it. Then handle the contents in the buffer as needed. This is esp. the case for global search, changes, etc. that have to be done on the file. After changes are done, one can then write the whole buffer to the same or other file at once, avoiding the risk to leave the the newly created file open -- by doing a lot readings and writings -- which is the worst case of all!