# make an basic TypeError?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this basic program that reads wind reading, it sorts by amount, min, max and average, and then creates a new file with the readings. However, I also want it to handle any exceptions that may occur during file operations and ensures that the file is always closed, even if an exception occurs.

*I'm very new to python, and numpy so I'm asking for help on how to solve this.*

I might have phrased it wrong. I want the error handling to do this: If the txt file contains a string or something else, the program shouldn't crash, but instead close the file and then stop the script

```
import numpy as np


def main():
    # Converts into a numpy array.
    # loadtxt function has the default dtype as float
    x = np.loadtxt("wind.txt")
    print("There are", len(x), "")
    print('Average:', np.average(x))
    print('Max:', np.amax(x))
    print('Min:', np.amin(x))

    file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
    file.write(f"Amount: {len(x)}\n")
    file.write(f"Average: {np.average(x)}\n")
    file.write(f"Max: {np.amax(x)}\n")
    file.write(f"Min: {np.amin(x)}\n")
    file.close()


main()
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I might have phrased it wrong. I want the error handling to do this: If the txt file contains a string or something else, the program shouldn't crash, but instead close the file and then stop the script.

Comment: Put a standard `try/except` clause around the `loadtxt` line.  Use `except ValueError` (or what ever error it raises with the string fault.).  But I strongly suspect `loadtxt` properly closes the file it is reading.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't know how to write code as a comment, but should it look like this then: https://imgur.com/a/HJDEVzg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do files get closed during an exception exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577137/do-files-get-closed-during-an-exception-exit)

Comment: @IonicSolutions Not quite.

Comment: What exactly is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadtxt` is a rather long function, but regarding its file handling:

```
fown = False
try:
    if isinstance(fname, os_PathLike):
        fname = os_fspath(fname)
    if _is_string_like(fname):
        fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
        fencoding = getattr(fh, 'encoding', 'latin1')
        fh = iter(fh)
        fown = True
    else:
        fh = iter(fname)
        fencoding = getattr(fname, 'encoding', 'latin1')
except TypeError:
    raise ValueError('fname must be a string, file handle, or generator')

...

try:
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
        if X is None:
            X = np.array(x, dtype)
        else:
            nshape = list(X.shape)
            pos = nshape[0]
            nshape[0] += len(x)
            X.resize(nshape, refcheck=False)
            X[pos:, ...] = x
finally:
    if fown:
        fh.close()
```

In sum, if you give it a file name (a string) it opens it and notes that it `owns` the file.  That actual file reading, and parsing to `dtype` is protected by a `try/finally` clause.  If it owns the file, it then closes it.

So if you get a `ValueError` due to a string that can't be converted to a float, you don't have to worry about closing the file.  In fact you couldn't even if you wanted to, since you don't have access to the `fh` handle.

If you want your code to do something different after this value error, wrap it:

```
In [126]: try: 
     ...:     np.loadtxt(["1 2 two"]) 
     ...: except ValueError: 
     ...:     print('got a value error') 
     ...:                                                                                        
got a value error
```

Or to modify your `main`:

```
def main():
    # Converts into a numpy array.
    # loadtxt function has the default dtype as float
    try:
         x = np.loadtxt("wind.txt")
    except ValueError:
         print('error reading "wind.txt")
         return   # skips the rest
    print("There are", len(x), "")
    print('Average:', np.average(x))
    print('Max:', np.amax(x))
    print('Min:', np.amin(x))

    file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
    file.write(f"Amount: {len(x)}\n")
    file.write(f"Average: {np.average(x)}\n")
    file.write(f"Max: {np.amax(x)}\n")
    file.write(f"Min: {np.amin(x)}\n")
    file.close()
```